# Tomcat CLASSPATH

Tags: tomcat, xerces

I have a very annoying problem:

My project (JSP, Servlet) requires Xerces-J 2.8.1 or higher. But on our server (Tomcat 5.5) xerces 2.6.2 always comes up first and that results in a severe error.

I checked $CLASSPATH and did some clean-ups. However, xerces 2.6.2 is still there. Could anyone tell me how to know where this xerces 2.6.2 is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the environment variable `$CLASSPATH` (and its Windows equivalent `%CLASSPATH%`) is **ignored** by *anything else* than the Java runtime command (`java.exe` in Windows) which is been executed *without* any of the `-cp`, `-classpath` and `-jar` arguments. Don't confuse this term as being the *real* classpath. That environment variable is just intented as (poor) convenience for starters who doesn't want to type the whole `-cp` or `-classpath` argument everytime.

As to your actual problem, Tomcat internally also uses Xerces to parse XML files as outlined in [this document](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html#XML%20Parsers%20and%20J2SE%201.4). If you have full control over the server, then best what you can do is to place the newer Xerces JAR file in the `/common/endorsed` folder, as explained in the document.

Answer (score 1):

If you're including the Xerces jar in your web app then it depends on how classloading is configured for your application and/or server.  There's information about that here:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html